# Flutter Firebase Filestore - Casting a returned List<dynamic> into List<CustomObject>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting back a list of BaseObjects from my firebase database.
This works fine.

On these objects is an array of CustomObjects.

When returning the list of BaseObjects I also want to cast the custom objects into an actual list of CustomObject.

So on the firebase database:

```
BaseObject:
   title: 'example'
   custom_objects: // array
     0
       'name 0'
     1
       'name 1'
```

In my application I have a model file for both BaseObject and CustomObject

so then when I retrieve the list of BaseObjects it works fine.
The issue is if I try to get the array of CustomObjects within each BaseObject.

```
Stream<List<BaseObject>> get baseObjects {
  return baseObjectCollection.snapshots().map(_baseObjectListFromSnapshot);
}

List<BaseObject> _baseObjectListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
    final baseObject = BaseObject(
      title: doc.data['title'] ?? '',
      customObjects: List<CustomObject>.from(doc.data['custom_objects']) ?? [],
    );

    return baseObject;
  }).toList();
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
Exception:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'CustomObject'
```

UPDATE:

```
I fixed it by doing:

        customObjects: List<CustomObject>.from(doc.data["custom_objects"].map((item) {
              return new CustomObject(
                title: item["title"] ?? '',
              );
            },),) ?? [],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

I fixed it by doing:

```
    customObjects: List<CustomObject>.from(doc.data["custom_objects"].map((item) {
          return new CustomObject(
            title: item["title"] ?? '',
              );
            },
          ),
        ) ?? [],
```